# "The office of the President" or "the office of President"?

Tags: definite-articles, legalese

I know this one by heart: it is Section 1 of the 22nd Amendment to the U.S. Constitution.

It sounds perfectly natural to me. I don't know why, though. Here:

> Section 1. No person shall be elected to **the office of the President** more than twice, and no person who has held **the office of President**, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to **the office of the President** more than once. But this article shall not apply to any person holding **the office of President** when this article was proposed by the Congress, and shall not prevent any person who may be holding **the office of President**, or acting as President, during the term within which this article becomes operative from holding **the office of President** or acting as President during the remainder of such term.

Behold: Twice, the post is referred to as "the office of the President," and four times as "the office of President."

Why?

Comment: Well, it consistently corresponds to the verb in this passage, in the sense that people are always *elected* "to the office of **the** President" but they *hold* "the office of President." Beats me why there's a difference in the use of the article between these two expressions, however.

Comment: Great question. I will be back after running 15 miles thinking about this. I think I can answer the question.

Comment: As a native speaker, who understands grammar by instinct rather than by rule, I would suggest that the only place the definite article is required, if at all, is in the first reference. Quite why the compiler included it a second time is unclear to me. Note that the article precedes *office* in every instance, which is perhaps significant. You could rewrite the whole piece, eliminating *the office of* throughout and no article would be required anywhere. You would need to change *held* to *been* in a couple of places however.

Comment: @WS2: _Note that the article preceded office in every instance, which is perhaps significant._ How's that? " ... has held office of ... " "... elected to office of ..."  Doesn't make much sense without the article. I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Ricky I'm not suggesting it is incorrect. But I'm just thinking that the article which precedes *office* is the one that is contextually driven. The definite article is there throughout emphasising that it is THE all important office of President which is under reference and not any old *office of President*. The *the* which precedes *President* is simply governed by the idiomatic phrase *Office of President*, or *Office of the President* - both of which work in any of the situations under scrutiny.

Comment: @WS2: Let me see if I understand this. You're saying that if it weren't the office of President, but rather, say, the office of the Abominable Snowman of El Paso, the definite article wouldn't have to be used as often? ... or what are you saying? Sorry. I'm kind of slow today.

Comment: @Ricky Well, if you read it again when you get up speed you will see that is NOT what I was saying. It is merely that whether you say *Office of President* or *Office of the President* is purely a matter of choice and not governed in any way by the context. However whether you put the def. art. in front of *office* is determined by the context.

Comment: You should put a bounty on this and wait until someone who has a background in constitutional law and history can shed some light on this.

Comment: I looked through some of the other amendments, and "the" is used or not used in other places which are quite interesting...for example amendment 24 section 2 uses "The Congress" when it seems "Congress" can stand alone without "The."

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Those are two different things, though. The one without the article refers to the session; the one with the article is the name of the government's legislative branch.

Comment: +1 as usual, but let me think why I disagree with this logic. Cause I do. I'm just having a hard time figuring out why.

Comment: @Ricky I dunno...this one needs an expert's touch...it was written by lawyers and people who knew the constitution...summelic has a point about elected to and held...but I can't say for sure.  But this is a cool question and should get everyone steamed up around here.

Comment: @michael_timofeev I think you are reading far too much into this, as though it was handed down on tablets of stone from the Almighty. I don't think the definite article is appropriate in any of them. Surely one only says *the President* if one is talking about a specific president, doesn't one? But who am I to opine on such matters.  We don't have anything comparable because the Queen doesn't occupy an office, only a throne.

Comment: @WS2 it's possible I am, but upon looking through the constitution I have noticed other curious cases or missing or applied articles that strike me as unusual...unusual when compared to everyday speech or what we think we know about articles...btw, who says the constitution didn't come from The Office of The Almighty?

Comment: @WS2: Well, you do have that Prime Minister dude at 10 Downing Street. Unless of course that's just a front. I wouldn't be surprised. Ever since Johnny signed that funny document back in 1199, the political structure of that weird country of yours has been very confusing. I mean, since Gibraltar still hasn't been granted independence and all, shouldn't the lady be styled Empress rather than Queen? Sheesh.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Without doubt the definite article brings more regality to the title *President*. And that may confirm some political scientists' views that the US President is, in effect, an elected monarch - (George III for a four year term) treated with more reverence than the UK Prime Minister who is only a commoner,  abused right, left and centre in the chamber of that name.

Comment: Outside of any context, if I see/hear "the office of President" I think of the person holding that office.  If I see/hear "the office of the President" I think of the room where the President sits and/or the people and files and computers and whatnot that sit in and around that room

Answer (score 1):

The office of **the** President in the Amendment means the [**presidency**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presidency) which is defined as:

> the job of a president or the period of time when a person is
> **president**
>
> Note: **the** is not used before president even though it is not capitalized in the definition.

The reason to use the definite article [*the*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the) is to show that the President is **unique** or a **particular member of its class** as indicated in Merriam-Webster's definition:

> The is used as a function word to indicate that a following noun or noun
> equivalent is a unique or a particular member of its class: *the
> President*, *the Lord*

However, when someone is elected to the office of **the** President, the noun **President** becomes a **proper noun** which doesn't require any articles before it as in:

> King George, Queen Elizabeth, President Obama, Prime Minister Cameron,
> Prefessor Jones, Father Smith, Judge John, Sir Walter Scott, etc.
>
> Note: There are exceptions; The Emperor Napoleon, The Czar Nicholas.

The reason we don't use **the** in the above examples is there is only one person who is called that way during his/her term as President, Prime Minister, Father, etc, which makes those nouns a **proper** noun.

When you read the Amendment, you will notice that *President* without **the** is referring to any existing President who has been elected to the **Office of the President** and all **office of President**'s were used as **objects** of the verb **hold** and **President**'s were used as objects of the preposition **as**.

[The oath of office of **the** President of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_office_of_the_President_of_the_United_States) has the following wording.

> I do solemnly swear (or affirm) that I will faithfully execute **the
> Office of President** of the United States, and will to the best of my
> ability, preserve, protect and defend the Constitution of the United
> States.

The reason why there is no **the** in the oath is the same as the 21st Amendment. President of the United States is just one person who can have maximum 2 terms.

[Merriam-Webster, Wikipedia]

Comment: I'm afraid that is about as clear as mud to me. Incidentally it is only Americans who say *Prime Minister Cameron*, *Prime Minister Trudeau* etc. In Britain we would say *David Cameron, the Prime Minister*. Or we might say The Prime Minister, David Cameron. (note the comma). *Prime Minister* is not actually a title of address in the way that *President *is. But these questions of forms and articles are just idiomatically driven, tradition being the only justification, in my view.

Comment: @WS2 What is the difference among Mr/Madam President, Mr/Madam Prime Minister, Mr/Madam Ambassador, etc. Aren't they all a title of address? I don't think **President** in the 21st Amendment and the oath is a title of address. It is a title of office, too I believe.

Comment: @Rathony Yes, I think *President* is both a title of office and of address. People do sometimes say *Mr Prime Minister* (We have only ever had one Madam Prime Minister, but the least said about her the better), but more often just *Prime Minister*. With Ambassadors, the formal method of address is *Your Excellency*, or *His Excellency the Ambassador of the United States*.

Comment: @WS2 I think I could see some pattern on how BrE speakers treat foreign leaders' titles. Anyway, is my explanation not clear about why the **the** is not used when describing President who is elected for 2 terms? Any better idea to explain it?

Comment: Instead of *proper noun* you mean the term President (Note capital letter)  is a title? E.g., Queen Elizabeth II, His Holiness Pope Francis, Sir Elton John etc. I would day Tsar/Czar Nicholas without the article. Emperor of France, surely? Not The Emperor Napoleon. (But I'm not too sure about this one)

Comment: @Mari-LouA President could be a title, but President Obama is a proper noun. There will be only one President Obama in the history.

Comment: Please keep comments on-topic: that is, requesting clarification of a post.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one elected (titular) 'President' at a time, the definite article is not needed.  I would have omitted it everywhere, lest anyone think that the 'office' was merely referring to the room that he sits in, although that is where he goes when elected, and he certainly can't hold it in his hands.

Answer (score 1):

It [seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Office_of_the_President) that *the office of **the** president* refers to the president's immediate staff - e.g. the assistants to the president, arising from Roosevelt's [reorganization act](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=15748).

The *office **of** president* refers to the specific role of presidency.

This difference is highlighted by the restriction that

> no person who has held the office of President ... [under certain conditions] ... shall be elected to the office of the President more than once.

This seems to be a restriction on former presidents becoming new vice presidents, etc.

A [possible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Interaction_with_the_Twelfth_Amendment) of this restriction:

> During Hillary Clinton's 2016 candidacy, she said that she had considered naming Bill Clinton as her Vice President, but had been advised it would be unconstitutional." (Edition.cnn.com, cited in Wikipedia)

Comment: I'm curious as to the reason for the down vote - I started with the assumption that the phrases were equivalent, but further reading suggested that this is not the case. The excerpt I extracted from the OP's quote is consistent with "office of the president" being different from "office of president".

Comment: I did not downvote you. I generally do not downvote answers. Downvoting answers just isn't my style.